# How to access pipeline variables in conditions

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have pipeline where running template as one of steps.

I need execute template with two different scopes of parameters depends on value of one of pipeline variable.

For example, if pipeline variable 'mode' has value 'dev', I need run template with one scope, if value is 'stage', another scope.

```
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.mode, 'dev') }}:
    - template: ../template.yaml
      parameters:
          mode: dev
          namespace: dev-namespace
          fqdn: dev-fqdn

    
  - ${{ if eq(variables.mode, 'staging') }}:
    - template: ../template.yaml
      parameters:
        mode: staging
        namespace: staging-namespace
        fqdn: staging-fqdn
```

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this syntax `${{ if eq(variables['mode'], 'staging') }}:`

Answer (score 0):

It depends at what time the variables will be [read in at and used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch). There are more then possible answer.
[image]

If using these for the future execution of a template I'd recommend using condition and defining the parameters you have in separate yml variable files.

```
  condition:  eq('${{ variables.mode}}', 'staging)
```

That way the call would be just

```
   job:
    condition:  eq('${{ variables.mode}}', 'staging')
    variables: staging.yml
    - template: ../template.yaml
      parameters:
        mode: ${{ variables.mode }}
        namespace: ${{ variables.namepsace }}
        fqdn: ${{ variables.fqdn }}
```

And staging.yml would look like:

```
variables:
   mode: staging
   namespace: staging-namespace
   fqdn: staging-fqdn
```

This way it is a little less decoupled and scalable not having to hard code it every time.

Answer (score 0):

1.If you're using [runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#use-parameters-in-pipelines), you can use this format:

```
trigger:
- master

parameters:
- name: mode
  displayName: Choose mode
  type: string
  default: dev
  values:
  - dev
  - staging

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.mode, 'dev') }}:
    - template: template.yml
      parameters:
        mode: dev
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.mode, 'staging') }}:
    - template: template.yml
      parameters:
        mode: staging
```

For more details you can check [Parameters to select a template at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters-to-select-a-template-at-runtime).

2.If you're using variables defined in yaml directly, check my another sample:

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  mode: staging

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:
- stage: Dev
  condition: eq(variables.mode, 'dev')
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
      - template: template.yml
        parameters:
          mode: dev

- stage: Staging
  condition: eq(variables.mode, 'staging')
  jobs:
  - job:
    steps:
      - template: template.yml
        parameters:
          mode: staging
```

I would recommend **runtime parameters** way cause it's more convenient and much more flexible.

**Update1:**

Here's my simple `template.yml` file which is just for test:

```
parameters:
- name: mode
  type: string
  default: default

steps:
- script: echo ${{ parameters.mode }}
```